# Firebase Pod installation issue

Tags: ios, firebase, cocoapods, xcode10.1

I am facing problem to install pod for Firebase In-App Messaging.
In my code, I have already firebase pod installed("Firebase/core") on platform 9.0. Now I want to integrate Firebase In-App Messaging in my app, so try to install the pod for Firebase In-App Messaging on Xcode 10.1. But get the error : "[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "Firebase/InAppMessagingDisplay":
  In Podfile:
    Firebase/InAppMessagingDisplay

None of your spec sources contain a spec satisfying the dependency: `Firebase/InAppMessagingDisplay`.

You have either:
 * out-of-date source repos which you can update with `pod repo update` or with `pod install --repo-update`.
 * mistyped the name or version.
 * not added the source repo that hosts the Podspec to your Podfile.

Note: as of CocoaPods 1.0, `pod repo update` does not happen on `pod install` by default."

I tried all the things which are given on google and stack flow.
I update my pod file, I also update cocoa pod. I tried every possibility but not able to fix my problem.

Comment: clean your project. remove your pod file. reinit your pod. install pod again.

Comment: I have already tried this.

Comment: paste your POD file.

Comment: just now I removed "Firebase/core" from podfile and on terminall run the command Pod install and again in podfile right this pod 'Firebase/Core', '~> 5.7.0'
pod 'Firebase/InAppMessagingDisplay' and pod get installed but when i run the project in xcode get the error "Module 'Firebase' not found". I clean the project and restart the xocde and my systme too still getting same error. Please help.

Comment: platform :ios, '10.1'
workspace 'default'

target 'abc' do
project 'abc.xcodeproj'
workspace 'default'
pod 'GoogleMobileVision/BarcodeDetector'
pod 'Firebase/Core', '~> 5.7.0'
pod 'Firebase/InAppMessagingDisplay'

Comment: do this  pod 'Firebase/Core'
 pod 'Firebase/InAppMessagingDisplay'    remove your version number.  It will install latest version from Firebase. Current ver is 5.15.0

Comment: https://github.com/evollu/react-native-fcm/issues/826 .

Comment: remove the version from  'Firebase/Core' but still facing the same issue. I also try to write command pod deintegrate and again write pod install command but no use. facing same error Module 'Firebase' not found

Comment: if possible then share ur project

Answer (score 0):

Remove version number and try to run as below

```
pod 'Firebase/Core'
pod 'Firebase/InAppMessagingDisplay'
```